# How can I get the Hibernate Reverse Engineering wizard to find tables in Microsoft SQL Server database with integrated security?

Tags: java, sql-server, hibernate, netbeans

I'd like to use the Hibernate Reverse Engineering Wizard in my web application project. Unfortunately, I cannot connect to the database (see image below) with the `hibernate.cfg.xml` set to

```xml
<hibernate-configuration>
  <session-factory>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:sqlserver://localhost\DATABACKEND:1433;databaseName=Example;integratedSecurity=true;</property>
    <property name="hibernate.default_schema">dbo</property>
  </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

[image]

I can connect to the same database without any problem in the Services explorer with the URL connection string `jdbc:sqlserver://localhost\DATABACKEND:1433;databaseName=Example;integratedSecurity=true;` and the schema set to `dbo` (see image below).

[image]

I can also connect if I use SQL authentication on the server, instead of integrated Windows authentication. But as this is less secure, I'd prefer to use integrated authentication, which works just fine (as shown above) in the Services explorer.

I searched around for help, but other similar questions (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19759825/hibernate-reverse-engineering-wizard-available-tables-empty-issue) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7861351/hibernate-reverse-engineering-in-netbeans-cannot-find-sql-server-tables)) don't have answers that help. I'm running Netbeans 8.0.2, Microsoft SQL Server 2014, and SQLJDBC 4.2.